# WebView vanishes for a second after opening another activity

Tags: android, webview

I have a `WebView` I add to an `Activity` with `setContentView()`. In this `WebView` I have a button that opens another `Activity` on top of the current one (using `startActivityForResult()`), this `Activity` dismisses itself after finishing its task, and we return to the first `Activity` (The one with the `WebView`). When returning to the `Activity` the `WebView` vanishes for a moment and we see the `Activity`'s background (it comes back after a second). This is annoying and looks glitchy. I'm not really sure why it happens, but it has something to do with invalidation of the `WebView` and it being `INVISIBLE` for a second (This is probably the way android renders its views or something...). Is there a fix for this?

This behavior only happens when hardware acceleration is enabled, disabling it fixes the issue, but I need hardware acceleration for the `WebView`.

**EDIT**: Some code

```
// A self dismissing activity
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView v = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFFFF0000);
        setContentView(v);

        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
            TestActivity.this.finish();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

// Code to show the WebView and then the activity, stick this somewhere in a different Activity
WebView wv = new WebView(getApplicationContext());
wv.loadUrl("www.google.com");
addContentView(wv, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

(new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent I = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TestActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(I, 255);
    }
 }, 1000);
```

This is much simpler than my actual code, but it replicates the result nicely.

Comment: Post some code in order help you ...